# How to take the users input and see if it matches random image showing on screen

Tags: java, if-statement, android-edittext

I would like to get the users input from an editText and check if it's equal to a random array image. How can I take the users input and see if it matches the image showing?

This is the code I use to get a random image from the array:

```
images[rand.nextInt(images.length)]
```

here is my code:

```
public void enterButton(View view) {
    String imageTitle = ImageDrawable.getTitle(); 
    String guess = userGuess.getText().toString();

    if (imageTitle == guess) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Correct!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Try Again!", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}


Drawables[] drawables = ...;
String[] titles = ...;
ImageDrawable[] imageDrawables = new ImageDrawable[drawables.length];
 if (drawables.length != titles.length) {
    throw ...;
}
for (int i=0;i<drawables.length;i++) {
    imageDrawables[i] = new ImageDrawable(drawable, titles[i]);
}
```

Comment: It's a bit difficult to understand what exactly do you want to achieve. Please add a minimal, reproducable example, which has the complete code flow :)

Comment: If `getText()` returns a `String` (likely), there's no need to add `.toString()` to it. What class is `View`? Does it have something like a `getName()` method that you want to compare to user input? If so, try `if (userGuess.getText().equals(view,getName()))`. Note the use of `.equals()` instead of `==` when comparing Strings.

Comment: @OferArial I understand i didn't explain this well. In my app there is a random picture from an array on the top of the screen and under it is an editText. The user enters in the edittext what they think is in that picture and gets a toast displaying whether they are right or wrong. The if statement for this is a bit hard. how do I say if the entered text is equal to that picture? I'm not sure if I should use the items id or?

Comment: @husky7110 Give me a concrete example. What will appear in the image, and what do you want the user to write? And also - what is the bigger picture here - what is the purpose of the app?

Comment: Is this a sort of a captcha, or is it more like AI training?  It seems like you're asking the user to see a picture of a toaster, and then type 'toaster' in the text box...  Does the app already know that the expected response is 'toaster' somehow?

Comment: @OferArial Let's say I have an array with 3 drawables in it. I use a piece of code to get a random drawable out of those (Say an image of a cat) and set it as the background of the imageView in my app. Now, the user sees the cat and starts typing in an editText "cat" and clicks on the enter button. Then they get a toast displaying whether their guess was right or wrong.

Comment: @Gus No its just a simple guessing game but there is more to it.

Comment: OK, so you can put the image and the correct guess for that image in the same object -- so your image display would display the picture from `imageObj.image` and compare the user's guess to `imageObj.correctGuess`

Answer (score 0):

Based on the detailed explanation the PO gave in the question's comments, this is my proposal:

Basically we have an image with something in it (e.g. a cat), and the user needs to insert his guess, saying what's in the image. The app should display a feedback message - if the user was right or wrong.

I propose this edit to your code, which is based on an object `imageDrawable`. This object will contain a field which is the `imageTitle`, which is the field you will compare to the user's guess.

The `imageDrawable` object should be a object you create. It can wrap the basic `Drawable`, and it can be a whole new object that has the path to the actual `Drawable` resource. I think that using a custom object will be the clearest way write it, and it also makes it easy to control the image title.

```java
public void enterButton(View view) {
    String imageTitle = imageDrawable.getTitle(); // TODO: implement imageDrawable with ImageDrawable class and initialize it
    String guess = userGuess.getText().toString();

    if (imageTitle == guess)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Correct!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Try Again!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

For example, if we have a `Drawables` array, we can transform it to an `ImageDrawables` array, also using image titles, and then use that array. (You should still implement `ImageDrawable` class).

```java
Drawables[] drawables = ...;
String[] titles = ...;
ImageDrawable[] imageDrawables = new ImageDrawable[drawables.length];
if (drawables.length != titles.length) {
    throw ...;
}
for (int i=0;i<drawables.length;i++) {
    imageDrawables[i] = new ImageDrawable(drawable, titles[i]); 
}
```

And then use `imageDrawables`.

Comment: For the imageDrawable part. were you referring to a specific drawable or a drawable array?

Comment: @husky7110 I added some explanation

Comment: when i tried this in my app many errors occurred, and im also not sure what this line of code is supposed to do int i=0;i<drawables.length;i++

Comment: The code I wrote isn't complete, you'll have to fill in the gaps. You can upload your current code as a question's EDIT, and I'll look at it :)

Comment: ok, so in: imageDrawable.getTitle(); i created a class called imageDrawable and then the getTitle(); becomes an error, and what am i supposed to fill in the ... ?

Comment: Add your current code to the original question...

Comment: try to check my code:

Comment: In the `...` sections - I meant that you will use your own code there. And you also still have to implement the ImageDrawable class. I don't want to write out the entire solution myself..